# LEDs on Dimmer switch turn off from another switch

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting

I’ve just installed LED down lights in bathroom and hallway. The light in the bathroom is a single LED and turns on/off correctly. There are 4 LED lights in the hall connected to a Trailing Edge dimmer switch. These operate normally, however, when the hall lights are on and the bathroom light is switched on it occasionally turns the hall lights off. They are all on the same lighting circuit. I’ve checked the wiring and am sure I’ve done it correctly but am perplexed on what I’ve done wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box for the bathroom light? (with the breaker off ofc)

Comment: Now changed dimmer to a standard switch and everything works fine, hall lights stayed on no matter how many times bathroom light was switched on/off! so frustrating- cannot understand why hall lights occasionally turn off when they were on a dimmer switch?

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer in question?

Comment: It’s a Varilight JQP401W, it was recommended as being one of the best dimmer switches for LEDs

Comment: I take it you're in the UK then?

Comment: Yes - I was a bit confused when you mentioned the switch box lol!